# Question about derivative symbolization when substituting

Tags: derivatives, substitution, chain-rule

Ι have a question concerning symbolization for derivatives when making a substitution.

For instance, let $f$ be a two variable function, where
$$ f(x,y)=x^2+y \quad , \; (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} $$
Then,
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2x $$
If we want to make a substitution, i.e. replace $x$ with another function $u(x)$ should we write
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \bigl (u(x),y \bigr )=2u(x) $$
or
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \bigl (u(x),y \bigr )=2u(x) $$

So, should we also replace $ \partial x $ with $ \partial u $ ?

If the first is true, doesn't it contradict the chain rule ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the second is correct.

Comment: In the first one, you'd have to multiply the right-hand side by $u'(x)$.  Just think of $y$ as some unknown constant.

Comment: @George G. Maybe do you mean that $x=x(u)$ and $y=y(u)$?